# Call to undefined method Imagick::setImageClipMask()

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick, php-7.2

I'm trying to run the example on [php.net/imagick.setimageclipmask](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.setimageclipmask.php) but with no luck.

Running it CLI and instead of returning the result, i save it to a file.

Anyone else run into a similar problem?

OS X 10.13.3, PHP 7.2.2, imagick module 3.4.3, ImageMagic 7.0.7-23

EDIT: I've tried to uninstall and completely reinstalled it via Brew.

```
Brew install -s imagemagic
brew install -s php72-imagick
```

Comment: check "php -m" on your terminal to check if imagemagic is not installed or disable

Comment: It's installed. I also see it in `php -i`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `MagickSetImageClipMask` & `MagickGetImageClipMask` methods have been deprecated & removed from ImageMagick 7. Because they no longer exist in the C-API `MagickWand` library, the PHP `Imagick` module excludes the methods.

To quote the source-code of [`imagick_class.c`](https://github.com/mkoppanen/imagick/blob/master/imagick_class.c#L1674) ...

```c
...
#if MagickLibVersion < 0x700
PHP_METHOD(imagick, setimageclipmask)
{
   ...
```

Either downgrade to ImageMagick-6, or jump over to the [developers forum](https://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/) & ask the authors what a preferred replacement/alternative would be.

Comment: Not the answer I was hoping for, but thank you very much! I must dig further to find a replacement then.